# Class public variables (Games)

Tags: c++, class, public

Would it be considered bad design to declare public variables in classes such as a character class for a game?

Example:

```
class Character{
public:
    Character();

    int health;

    void attack(int);
private:
    int attackPow;
};


void Character::attack(int hp){
    hp -= attackPow;
}


Character hero;
Character bad;

hero.attack(bad.health);
```

Because the health variable is public, I can directly modify it by calling it in a function, or even by taking the entire object and modifying its attributes to my whim, of course, also returning the entire object.

But, if the variable were private, I would have to have a seperate function to change the private variable, thus would make the code much more...cluttered..Or is there another way around this? (You'll have to excuse me, I'm not quite an expert yet, but very intriguing question, nontheless)

Is this considered bad practice though?

Comment: Presumably if the health is 0 or less the character dies right?  If anybody can poke at that variable how will you know that happened?  If it was encapsulated then you could check anytime it changed and handle the case appropriately.

Comment: Retired Ninja, didn't think of it like that..
thanks for shedding some light

Answer (score 2):

Here is an advantage of making the `health` attribute private and using a separate function. For now it might just look like this:

```
int getHealth() { return health; }
```

However, this is only the beginning states of the game. Imagine you wish to add a lot more factors, like shields persay, which you wished to be calculated on top of the current health. If in your code, you just used the public variable, you would now have to change all of it, ie;

```
hero.attack(bad.health + bad.shield);
```

This is a lot of work, in respect to changing one function:

```
int getHealth() { return health + shield; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of opinion based I guess, but here is what I think:

If you are sure that your class is just an aggregate of values that don't have invariants *and never will*, then you are looking for a `struct` where *all* data-members are `public`. This happens really rarely, something like

```
struct point {double x,y,z;};
```

might be an example.

Else, use a `class` with `private` members *only* and guard those invariants.

In your case you should chose a class with `private` members. You might for example want to do something every time health becomes less or equal than zero. You can only guarantee things like this for `private` members.

Answer (score -1):

> Would it be considered bad design to declare public variables in
>   classes such as a character class for a game?

Yes, of course.

But this is just a *guideline*, you know. In real code, in a real project, with colleagues, bosses, requirements, customers, deadlines, a legacy code base with thousands of dependencies, company politics and business psychology, [you may find yourself applying bad design because it's the right thing to do in the grand scheme of things](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/big-picture#use-evil-things-sometimes).

> But, if the variable were private, I would have to have a seperate
>   function to change the private variable, thus would make the code much
>   more...cluttered

If the variable is private,

- You do not even need a setter method if you don't want the variable to be modified from outside.
- You can change its type without changing many other source code files.
- You can change its name without changing many other source code files or relying on your environment's automatic refactoring features.
- You can restrict the range of the values the variable may have by adding error checks in the setter method.
- You can more easily add logging to see when the variable is modified by writing log output in the setter method
- You can more easily set up a break point for debugging by setting it in the setter method.
- You can more easily guarantee synchronised access to the variable if multiple threads are involved.

That's just what first comes to mind. The list can be much longer.

Private variables are the very core of creating structured, maintainable code in C++ (and other comparable programming languages).

Comment: Thanks for highlighting a lot of the benefits of private variables.
I still think hero.attack(bad.health) is much easier to read than,
    bad.setHealth((hero.attack(bad.getHealth());

Or is there another way around this cluttered-ness?  Maybe show me an example? :p

Comment: @savageWays: Put the attack into a free-standing wrapper function. Something like `void Attack(Character const &attacker, Character &target) { target.SetHealth(target.GetHealth() - attacker.GetStrength(); }` - then you can write `Attack(myHero, badOrc);`

Comment: I wonder what's wrong with the answer, by the way. Getting downvotes with no given reason tends to be somewhat frustrating; it's like someone saying "that's wrong" and not explaining why.

Comment: Tell me about it, I got downvotes for asking a valid question, even worded the question asking if its bad practice, and they give me downvotes like I'm saying its good to declare class public variables or something

Comment: @savageWays: Well, I think the question is quite opinion-based rather than being the precise technical problem in search of a direct solution; i.e. it is not exactly the kind of thing which SO considers its preferred subject area. However, the downvotes are very harsh indeed. I think downvoting an otherwise good question for being off-topic *is* OK, but not without any explanation.